# Isekai light novel about a powerful mage summoned to the middle of the forest, who could analyse the environment

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read this like 2-3 years ago. The main character is a powerful mage in his game and he got isekai. I think he was found dead on a snow mountain then got reincarnated into the new world.

I only remember some details as his name was Marion or Marian. He was summoned in the middle of the forest. He also used his skill to analyse the environment (leaves, etc) around him.

Comment: This is pretty brief, can you remember anything else about this that you could [edit] in? Why was he summoned? Who summoned him? Can you remember any of the plot/story?

Comment: No, I dont remember. I read this like 2-3 years ago. He was playing the game and I think he was found dead on a snow mountain then got reincarnated into the new world

Comment: @Yakeec Assuming you're the OP please follow the [instructions here to merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). You'll then be able to edit your question and comment on it again.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be *[Next Life](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/next-life)*.

[image]

> Yamada Takashi lost his life in the snowy mountains—that is what he thought, but he then appeared in an unknown place; another world that looked like the game he played. Moreover there are many things that he doesn't know... While puzzled, he still retains the strongest class ability and is relieved. High rank magician, "Wise man" Marius is still living till today.

Boy dies on a snowy mountain: check. Is reincarnated into a game he previously played: check. His character in the game world is a magician: check. Starts out in a forest: check. He also uses the name "Marius" in the game world.

Comment: @ojyakeec - Glad to help, but please [merge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts so you can [accept](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.